# some clarification on bounded functions?

Tags: real-analysis

what does it mean for a function in $L^p$ to be bounded? Is it safe for me to use the fact that if $f$ is bounded then $\exists N>0 s.t. |f|<N$?

Since f is in $L^p$ then $\int |f|^p <\infty$, if $f$ is bounded then what does it imply on the $\int |f|^p <\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be a bit careful with what you mean that $f \in L^p$. In general, functions in $L^p$ are not uniquely defined in the sense that they just have to be equal almost everywhere. For example, if you take your space to be $[0,1]$ and take an enumeration of the rationals there to be $q_n$ and define a function to be $f(q_n)=n$ and zero everywhere else, then this is obviously not a bounded function but in the sense of the $L^p$ space it is the same as the constant function zero. These are quotient spaces, so this is what is causing these phenomena.

Take a look at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum

However, if you just have a function which is defined everywhere on a space $X$ then saying that $f \in L^p$ is often common notation to simply denote that the integral you used is finite. So, if you know the function is bounded, by say $M$, then you can use the integral inequality to say that $\int_X |f|^p d\mu \leqslant M^p \mu(X)$ which can often be helpful if you have that $X$ has finite measure.

Comment: f is bounded on X so I guess then that f i defined almost everywhere on X. am i right?

Comment: You just always have to consider the setting from which you are asking the question. If you say that a function is bounded on $X$ usually you assume it is defined everywhere and you do whatever with it. But by studying Lp you dont study individual function, you study equivalence classes of functions, which are functions that are equal almost everywhere. So, you want them to be essentially bounded, because it is not as important to what happens on sets of measure zero.

Comment: i wanted to show that for $q<r$, if $f\in L^{q}$ then $f\in L^r$. given that $f$ is bounded on X. i am quite confused on how the boundedness of $f$ can help me to where I wanna go